# Why can't the element be found with the correct xpath using Inspector tool Chrome?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, web-inspector

Trying to get the xpath of an dynamically loaded element. The element represents a dot in a chart. It holds an attribute value I would like to extract. I use the Inspector tool in Chrome to get the xpath of the element. I can copy the xpath but when I try to paste in the copied xpath in the chrome inspector tool no element is found. I can find other elemens on the page using this method.

[image: Chrome Inspector tool error]

Why could this be? I can't find any iframe in the html nor any hidden element. My purpose is to find the xpath for this element to use it with Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dev tool aren't meant for tags like `svg, g, path, circle, canvas`. So you can not generate them automatically.

You can write `xpath` by your own for the mentioned `tags`, something like this :-

```
//*[name()='svg']
```

to locate an `svg` **tag**

let's say you want to write `xpath` for the highlighted item (screenshot), you could do something like this :-

```
//*[name()='g' and contains(@class, 'recharts-layer recharts-line-dot')]//*
```